# Error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, whatsapp, nonetype

```
    def punto_verde(self):
    try:
        position =  pt.locateOnScreen("punto.png", confidence= .7)
        pt.moveTo(position[0:2], duration = self.speed)
        pt.moveRel(-100, 0,duration = self.speed)
        pt.doubleClick(interval= self.click_speed)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception (punto_verde):", e)
```

I'm making a bot for whatsapp and when I tried to run the code I got the error

> "Exception (punto_verde): 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

What is the mistake?

Comment: `locateOnScreen` is returning nothing. Does punto.png appears on the screen?

Comment: I think I have not understood very good the question but no, no "punto.png" appears